# change css element in react link is active

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make that if my navlink is active, change the color of `ListItemIcon` element to blue.

```
      <NavLink to="/dashboard">
        <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem}>
          <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
            <HomeIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText
            classes={{ primary: classes.primary }}
            inset
            primary={<FormattedMessage {...messages.dashboardItem} />}
          />
        </MenuItem>
      </NavLink>
```

Comment: And what is the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

For relatively small style changes you can just use the `style` property:

```
  <NavLink to="/dashboard">
    <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem}>
      <ListItemIcon style={{ color: navLinkIsActive ? 'blue' : 'black'}} className={classes.icon}>
        <HomeIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText
        classes={{ primary: classes.primary }}
        inset
        primary={<FormattedMessage {...messages.dashboardItem} />}
      />
    </MenuItem>
  </NavLink>
```

Comment: I dont understand, what is navLinkIsActive

Comment: @ReactRouter4 this is just a placeholder; you'd need to have a check for whatever it is that you're using to determine whether the link is active. Or do you mean active as in the css state?

Comment: How can i check, if navLinkIsActive is active true?

Comment: `navLinkIsActive` is just something I made up; it could be any conditional check. When you say "navlink is active", what do you mean exactly?